# UINavigationbar covers top of view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have set up a view with only one UITextView and a UINavigationBar in a xib file.

When I run the app, the top part of the text is obscured by the UINavigationBar, even though I lined up the UITextView in IB below the UINavigationBar.

It not only happens with UITextViews, also with other type of views, including a simple UILabel.  My understanding is that when using a navbar, the top of the views will be shifted down, but this doesn't happen.

Am I missing anything in my setup to prevent this?

Comment: How do you create UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change navigation bar `translucent` property.

As i see from the screenshot it is in the navigationcontroller

```
[[self.navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: That's it, thank you, thank you!! This has been driving me nuts for the last few days!