# On orientation change to landscape, UINavigationBar in second UIWindow has wrong height, which causes to cover top of view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow

I am using multiple UIWindows, app starts with first UIWindow, and sets up second UIWindow as following:

```
func onButtonPress() {
    let secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: self.sidebarRect)
    secondWindow.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TableViewController())
}
```

**Issue:** Second UIWindow's `UINavigationBar` has wrong height **ONLY** when app changes orientation from portrait to landscape, which causes to cover the view.

[image]

Height is correct (please check screenshots) when app launches second UIWindow in portrait or landscape.

[image]

I have tried followings:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15729536/1244597
2. `positionForBar` `UIBarPosition.topAttached`

I am not using autolayout for second UIWindow, another screenshot showing UIWindow is right on the edges of screen and not far

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the height is wrong, and that it's not just extended too far from the top?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @dfd, not using auto layout, manually updating frame of overlay UIWindow

Comment: @Pierce, yes sure height is wrong, please check last screenshot

Comment: @dfd, i found that the overlayUIWindow's UINavigationBar is having a 20pt gap from top in landscape orientation.

Comment: For now just using following workaround: main view controller (which is under overlay) is receiving UIDeviceOrientationDidChange notifications, within orientationChanged method i am updating secondUIWindow.rootViewController.UINavigationBar.frame.origin.y = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y